# Is there a difference between these ways of initialising a C array in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, array-initialization

I want to initialise all members of the array to zero, or `nullptr`

```
struct Window{ int a;};


int main()
{
    Window* list[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    Window* list2[4] = {0};
    Window* list3[4] = {};
    Window* list4[4]{ 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    Window* list5[4]{0};
    Window* list6[4]{};
}
```

I understand that when initialising at least one member to any value all the others are zero initialised, so if I do:

```
int list[4] = { 6 };
```

The first member becomes `6` and all the rest are zero-initialised. I'm confused however with:

```
int list[4]{0};
```

and

```
int list[4]{};
```

I assume that the empty squiggly brackets right after the declaration without an equals sign are what's called zero initialisation, as opposed to default initialisation, but so too is `int list[4]{0}`, isn't it? Does this involve an `std::initializer_list` behind the scenes or not? I thought these were only used for non-POD types, so `std::initializer_list` is not being used here?

Comment: They're all different forms of [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), and have the same final effect.

Comment: I love [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) It pretty much explains everything about [initializers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Comment: @lakeweb Thanks. Oh dear, it's different between C++03 and C++11, these are some very subtle things.

Comment: @Zebrafish the only difference relevant to your question is that `T list[4]{args, ...};` i.e. braced-init-list syntax that you use in your lists 4,5,6 was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @user2079303 Interesting, braced init list syntax but not initializer list. There are some really subtle differences here. After the equals they're aggregate initialisation or assignment, without the equals sign their braced-init-list syntax beginning from C++11, and yet the same thing for a non-POD type will turn the what's in the brackets into an std::initializer_list, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a difference between these ways of initialising a C array in C++?

No. They're semantically equivalent.

> zero initialisation, as opposed to default initialisation, but so too is int list[4]{0}, isn't it?

The first element is copy-initialized with zero. The rest of the elements are value initialized, which for `int` is indeed zero initialization. There is no effectual difference in value, zero and copy initialization with zero specifically in the case of `int` specifically. The distinction is syntactical in that case.

> Does this involve an std::initializer_list behind the scenes or not?

`std::initializer_list` is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pointer to store array in C++, it's too C styled :)

Use container instead. I always stick to `vector` to make array of object for general purposes. The initialization of the vector will follow the class constructor. Let me modify your `Window` class a little bit.

```
struct Window {
    // Class constructor
    Window(const int _a_) {
       a = _a_;
    }

    // Class member 
    int a;
};

std::vector<Window> windows (4, Window(0));
```

Your windows will contain 4 `Window` with zero-initialized value of `a`. Hope this answer your question.

Comment: I am pretty certain that OP is well-aware of containers. His question is about the differences among the specific language constructs.

Comment: Oh it's my bad. I jumped to the conclusion just by reading this `I want to initialise all members of the array to zero`.